# How can I programmatically make a window fullscreen?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

How can I programmatically make a window fullscreen?

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    scene = new QNewScene(this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    // here is some code that will make the window fullscreen


}
```

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(showFullScreen()));
```

method to make your window full screen:

```
QWidget::showFullScreen()
```

check it here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#showFullScreen

Comment: Why not calling `QWidget::showFullScreen()` full screen directly?

Comment: @apalomer Sure, you can do it. But maybe you need call it after 1 or 2 sec. I wrote two solutions for this.